# for some reason in pygame i cant move my space ship

Tags: python

I just want to make it move without any buttons it does not do anything.

```
import pygame

def player(x, y):
        screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

        
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
playerImg = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")

playerX = 350
playerY = 500
playerX_change = 0
playerX -= 2

running = True;
while running:
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

                screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
                player(playerX, playerY)
                
                playerX -= 1
                pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What **_does_** it do? What is your expected output? Without these details giving an answer is impossible.

Comment: I just want it to move automaticly when the screen loads i dont care if it goes off the screen its just a start.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your indentation: the updates happen *only* when you're ready to quit the game.  You can't move unless there's an `event` in the queue.  Fix it so that the changes come in the normal movement loop:

```
while running:

    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    
    playerX -= 1
    pygame.display.update()
```

You have to handle your event queue in some other fashion; see the appropriate tutorials for how to move asynchonously while responding to events.

Comment: it just says pygame window not responding do you know why?

Comment: No, I don't.  Did you include all of the required initialization?

Comment: This would be a separate SO question; I can't diagnose without accurate code.

Comment: what does SO mean?